# jQuery .find() with between 2 values

Tags: jquery, jquery-xml

Model xml:

```
<findkeyword id="1">
    <findinnertag>somevalue</findinnertag>
</findkeyword>
<findkeyword id="2">
    <findinnertag>somevalue</findinnertag>
</findkeyword>
<findkeyword id="3">
    <findinnertag>somevalue</findinnertag>
</findkeyword>
<findkeyword id="4">
    <findinnertag>somevalue</findinnertag>
</findkeyword>
<findkeyword id="5">
    <findinnertag>somevalue</findinnertag>
</findkeyword>
```

How to find the id values between 2 to 4 from the above xml using find keyword jquery xml

In this case, how to write parameters the inside of find keyword.

$(xml).find("findkeyword[id]")?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(xml).find('findkeyword').filter(function() { return this.id.match('[2-4]'); });
```